# Delete stored procedure in Oracle which uses a point within the name

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure in my oracle schema which contains a point within the name.

If a run the query

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from all_objects
```

I got:

```
owner: MYSCHEMA
object_name: MYPROC.NAME
object_type: PROCEDURE
```

I tried to delete this procedure using the quotation marks:

```
drop procedure "MYSCHEMA.MYPROC.NAME"
```

But it was unsucessful. How do I delete this SP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:

```
drop procedure MYSCHEMA."MYPROC.NAME";
```

Comment: Joao - this solution should work. If it doesn't, it'll be because the double quotes also make the name case sensitive, so make sure you get the case right. I'd also recommend using "standard" names so you don't run into this type of problem in the future.

Comment: If an object was created with mixed case letters, enclosed in double quotes, then data dictionary view would show the name as it was specified during creation of the object. Example: CREATE TABLE "miXED_casE_tesT" (x NUMBER); SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE upper(table_name) = 'MIXED_CASE_TEST'; -- returns miXED_casE_tesT table name